# How Can I Check if a Tkinter Text Widget Was Edited Without Using Define Statements?

Tags: python, tkinter

So basically I want to make a Tkinter text widget know if it was edited without using this method of using define statements.

The reason why I don't want to use this is because I can't put any text into the text widget when doing this.

This is the method I don't want to use:

```
Edit_Text = False

Textbox1 = Text(root, height=30, width=30)

Textbox1.pack()

def Edit_Was_Made(event:tkinter.Event) -> str:
    global Edit_Text
    Edit_Text = True
    return "break"

Textbox1.bind("<Key>", Edit_Was_Made)
```

Is there any way of not using this and still being able to check if it was edited?

Comment: you have to use `global Edit_Text` inside function to assign new value to external variable `Edit_Text`. At this moment it creates local variable `Edit_Text` and it doesn't change external variable `Edit_Text`

Comment: why you don't want to use this method? And if you want to do something when text was edited then you should do it directly inside `Edit_Was_Made`. `GUI` doesn't work like normal text programs and other code may not wait for information about `Edit_Text = True`

Comment: I think it can be the only way to get this information.

Comment: maybe you should answer for question: `why don't you want to use this method?` If you have some problem with this function then describe it. Maybe your real problem need totally different solution and you search solution in wrong place. maybe you have [XYProblem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: You don't need to keep a global flag. The text widget maintains a flag that can be used to know if it has been modified or not. See [The Modified Flag](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.11/TkCmd/text.htm#M87) in the official tk documentation.